# Easier scrolling of pages with "screen"

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

Inside a SSH session to a distant server, I use `screen` (similar tu `tmux`).

I know that, in order to scroll with <kbd>PG-UP</kbd> / <kbd>PG-DOWN</kbd>, one has to do this before:

<kbd>CTRL+A</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>

This is not very handy.

**Is there a way to configure `screen` to have something like <kbd>SHIFT + PG-UP</kbd> / <kbd>SHIFT + PG-DOWN</kbd> to scroll pages (or mouse scrolling), inside a SSH terminal?** (without having to do <kbd>CTRL+A, [</kbd>)

Without `screen`, scrolling in a terminal is just as easy as doing <kbd>SHIFT + PG-UP</kbd> / <kbd>SHIFT + PG-DOWN</kbd>.

Note: With `tmux`, [this](https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux) might be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keys like <kbd>SHIFT + PG-UP</kbd> / <kbd>SHIFT + PG-DOWN</kbd> are captured by your terminal and never make it to screen, so that key is not directly available.  It might be possible to rebind that to something that would make it to screen.

Also, screen is modal, in that <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> (or alternately, <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd> <kbd>ESC</kbd>) puts it it into copy mode.  Once in copy mode, the <kbd>PG-UP</kbd> / <kbd>PG-DOWN</kbd> keys work just fine for me.  Since exiting copy mode resets the scroll, it would not make sense to create a binding to enter copy mode, scroll, and then exit copy mode.  Since these single keys work already, I'm not sure how this could be improved unless you want to bind the 3 key sequence to enter copy mode to a key -- which likely would still have to be a two key sequence.

Comment: Thank you. The reason is: on FR keyboard, `CTRL +A [` is particularly unhandy. Indeed, to do `[`, one has to press `ALT GR + 5` ! That's why I want to avoid the entire thing of CTRL A, [

Comment: Do you have an ESC key?  Use that instead of [

Comment: @Basj, the default bindings are unhandy on non-US keyboards, but you can reconfigure the keybindings. I have `bind ' ' copy` and `bind . paste .` in `.screenrc` (two separate lines), thus binding Ctrl-A space to start copy mode, and Ctrl-A <dot> to paste. Space is nice for entering copy mode since you can also mark the copy area and exit copy mode by tapping on space. (of course you can also change the command key from Ctrl-A to something else. The default being annoying in particular if you're used to using Ctrl-A in the Emacs sense of "go to start of line")

Comment: @ilkkachu Oh this is great, please post your comment as an answer, it solves my problem of `CTRL A [` unhandyness!

Comment: @user10489 `CTRL+A ESC` is good too!

Comment: I frequently rebind ctrl-a myself, especially when running screen inside screen.  :)  Actually, I never use ctrl-a [ but always ctrl-a esc anyway.